# Unset array element based on first character

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Im trying to find a way to unset an element if the first character is a certain letter, in this case the letter D... I'm not sure if there is an array function to do something of the sort or if a preg replace would do the trick?

```
[0] => Aaron [1] => Bob [2] => Carl [3] => Dale [4] => Devin [5] => Dylan
```

Unset all words that start with letter "D" Would result in:

```
[0] => Aaron [1] => Bob [2] => Carl
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Cool, you can use closures then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function:

```
function filter_firstchar($var){
    return $var[0] != 'D';
}

$result = array_filter($arr, 'filter_firstchar');
```

If the letter you are going to be filtering by is going to change, you can build a really basic filtering class:

```
class Filter_FirstChar {
    private $char;
    function __construct($char){
        $this->char = $char;
    }
    function filter($var){
        return $var[0] != $this->char;
    }
}

$result = array_filter($arr, array(new Filter_FirstChar('A'), 'filter'));
```

Comment: You need to use `!=` "If the callback function returns true, the current value from input is returned into the result array"

Comment: @GWW: Good call! I read the question too quickly and thought he wanted to *keep* the entries starting with 'D'. My bad.

Comment: I'm getting unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION on line 2 of the class?

Answer (score 3):

A manual loop accomplishes the task already. But as one-liner option:

```
 $array = preg_grep('/^(?!D)/', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
$n = count($array);
while ($i < $n) {
  if ($array[$i][0] == 'D')
    unset($array[$i]);
  ++$i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key => $name)
{
    if(substr($name,0,1) == "D")
    {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Is one method that could work well for you.